# Обработчик событий jQuery

Tags: jquery, события

Есть кнопки + и – и есть input в котором отображает кол-во заказов, всё вроде хорошо, но при клике + или – у всех позиций в других li меняет значение, вот код, буду благодарен за помощь:

```
var minus = $(‘.minus’),
plus = $(‘.plus’),
valIn = 1;
function changeInput(){
$(‘.quantity .prod-quantity’).val(valIn);
}
minus.click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
valIn–;
changeInput();
if( valIn < 1 ){
valIn = 1;
}
});
plus.click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
valIn++;
changeInput();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `$(‘.quantity .prod-quantity’)` возвращает несколько инпутов, а вам нужен только тот, напротив которого кликнули.
Если предположить такую html структуру:

```
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="prod-quantity">
  <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
  <a href="#" class="minus">-</a>
</div>
```

Тогда для плюса получим примерно следующее

```
plus.click(function(){
 $(this).parents(".quantity").find(".prod-quantity").val(function(i,oldval){
    return oldval++;
  })
})
```

Для минуса - по аналогии

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.parents is not a function

Comment: Ой! Сорри. $(this).parents.....